# kubernetes deployment run command

Tags: kubernetes

How can I run command line arguments in Kubernetes deployments?

I trird like this, but the deployment failed

```
   spec:
        containers:
          - args:
              - /bin/sh
              - '-c'
              - touch /tmp/healthy; touch /tmp/liveness
            env:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kubernetes deployment with args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53464642/kubernetes-deployment-with-args)

Answer (score 0):

You can run command line arguments in Kubernetes deployments using "kubectl".

Comment: As soon as I add 

          - args:
              - /bin/sh
              - '-c'
              - touch /tmp/healthy; touch /tmp/liveness
to the deployment file the application is not coming up , but without any error in the description logs.